# send Email without waiting for the action to finish execution

Tags: javascript, asp.net, c#-4.0, sendmail

i am trying to avoid the wait time, taken by sending an email 
before exiting page.

the page/application  is doing a sequence of actions before exiting as follows :

1. database interaction
2. Send Email (updates a manager about that transaction)
3. Exit page / application .

code behind function :

```
    ExecEntryOnTbl(SQL);// <-- update / insert to database 
    sendMailNote(action);// <-- send mail with notification of update 

    exitTC(action, custid);<-- exit page.

    done via javascript :
    window.location.href = "someOtherPage.aspx"
    from code behind via 
    RegisterClientScriptBlock(...)
```

i would like to solve the issue :

how can i avoid waiting for the `sendMailNote()` to complete 
before following `exitTC()` could be executed. is that possible ?

- update email class/method

  ```
  public static class mail
  {
      public static string aReciver, bSubject, cBody;
      public static void sendMailNoteExc()
      {

          string SmtpServer = "smtp.gmail.com";
          int port = 111;
          string sender = "aaa@bbb.com";
          string ReCiver = aReciver;
          string Subject = bSubject;
          string Body = cBody;
          string account = "acc@domain.com";
          string Pass = "a123456";
          Send(SmtpServer, port, account, Pass, sender, ReCiver, Subject, Body);

      }
      public static void Send(string smtpServer,int Port,string Account, string PassWord, string From, string To, string Subject, string Body)
      {

          MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
          SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient(smtpServer);

          mail.From = new MailAddress(From);
          mail.To.Add(To);
          mail.Subject = Subject;
          mail.Body = Body;


          SmtpServer.Port = Port;
          SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(Account, PassWord);
          SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;

          SmtpServer.Send(mail);


      }
  }
  ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as you are using C# 4.0 you can take advantage of [Task Parallel Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx) and run `sendMailNote(action)` in the background thread like this:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => sendMailNote(action));
```

Just make sure you add a code to handle any exceptions occured during sending an email. However the better solution would be to remove this logic from the user interface code altogether and execute it in a background task like windows service or cloud worker role.

Comment: did you see last answer `@Ehsan Aleem Avee` is it necessary to specify tasks properties inorder for them to act as specified?

Comment: or is this totally different class /methods he is using ?

Comment: The idea behind both answers is the same, but he is using a more low level API to use a background thread. If you are able to use TPL then I suggest you to do so as it is easier to use and will work faster as it is using .NET Framework thread pool instead of creating a new thread.

Answer (score 2):

Do it in another thread. as a result your main thread will not wait for email sending.

```
ExecEntryOnTbl(SQL);// <-- update / insert to database 

ThreadStart sendMail = delegate()
{
    sendMailNote(action)
};

Thread thread = new Thread(sendMail );
thread.IsBackground = true;
thread.Start();

exitTC(action, custid);<-- exit page.

done via javascript :
window.location.href = "someOtherPage.aspx"
from code behind via 
RegisterClientScriptBlock(...)
```

Comment: thanks , is there any difference to the answer that i've accepted as correct (it simply works ) your code tries setting thread properties... etc or did you not take into account the use of availble `Task parallel` when using c#4.0

Comment: I do not have knowledge of Task.Factory.StartNew functionality. But i think it also creates a new thread to accomplish job in asynchrnous way..

Answer (score 0):

You can persist the email info to a database, and have a background cron job that actually sends the mail.

Comment: can u please give a short example on how do you do it ? i will show you the actuall send mail function i am using , sound interesting (updating post)