# Django/Python: execute code (sending email) without waiting for it to finish then immediately response to the client side

Tags: python, django

My question is basically the Python version of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12941168/send-email-without-waiting-for-the-action-to-finish-execution):

code structure:

```
def save(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        ...
        email_obj.save()  # write data into database

        # the below sendmail step takes too long to finish
        # how to execute it without waiting for it to finish
        # then immediately run the last step: return render(request, 'success.html')
        sendmail(email_obj)  # 

        return render(request, 'success.html')
```

Comment: How long is too long??  Yes, it's legitimate to want to send mail asynchronously.. but.. unless you're generating some very complex report then emailing it, it shouldn't take more than a second or two.. usually less.  If you're communicating with a remote smtp server that's slow, you may want to run a local relayhost (eg. postfix) which will accept your mail quickly and then forward it without holding you back...

Answer (score 1):

You can employ **threading** to achieve this. Your code will look something like this -

```
import threading

def save(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    ...
    email_obj.save()  # write data into database

    # the below sendmail step takes too long to finish
    # how to execute it without waiting for it to finish
    # then immediately run the last step: return render(request, 'success.html')
    # This will create a thread for the function and asynchronously execute it
    email_thread = threading.Thread(target=sendmail, name="Email Thread", args=email_obj)
    email_thread.start() 

    return render(request, 'success.html')
```